# How to send http request to flask installed on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, httprequest, postman

I've tried to set up a flask restful api on EC2 and used postman to test a request, but it returned a method result not allowed after I started a debugging session. Here is my python file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app=Flask(__name__)
api=Api(app)

data={
        #angle
        "a":0,
        #hasStarted
        "hs":False
}

class Angle(Resource):

        def put(self):
                parser=reqparse.RequestParser()
                parser.add_argument("a")
                parser.add_argument("hs")
                args=parser.parse_args()

                data["a"]=int(args["a"])
                data["hs"]=bool(args["hs"])

                return 200

api.add_resource(Angle,"/")
app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the PUT request I sent via postman:

`ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/?a=10&hs=True`

Also, I opened http (port 80), so should I use api.add_resource(Angle,"/var/www/html") instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The reason is that I've already run apache on port 80, I opened 443 and ran my flask app there and it worked